# How to check if there is a certain element between two rooms of a two-dimensional array in java

Tags: java

So I'm making this game in which there is an n*n board and the board is filled with walls and stars. Players have to get the stars to win but can't get past walls

The problem is, I don't know how to handle a wall blocking the path. See below for image explanation:

[image]

In the scenario above, if you click on the bottom left house it shouldn't let you move there but I don't know how to implement that in my code.

All the items are in a 2-dimensional array named blocks[][]. each blocks[i][j] stores an Item and in our case the block under the player stores an Item with the subclass of Wall.

I would be thankful if you guys helped me out.

Cheers!

Comment: if (blocks[i][j].equals(wall))?

Comment: How does one search between the block that the player is currently on to the block the user clicked on. That's the main issue here. Is there a certain method for it? Or there is some kind of algorithm

Comment: That's a different question.  Research breadth-first search.

Comment: When you speak of _...search[ing] between the block that the player is currently on to the block the user clicked on_, what exactly do you mean by "between"?  Along a single row/column/diagonal?   Or along _any connected path_ of adjacent unobstructed cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to check the array elements between the current position and the destination. Since the player can only move horizontally or vertically, you can loop through that (the direction the player is heading) of the array and search for "wall". Thank you all for helping me out